# Disable the whole select tag once selected an option

Tags: javascript, html

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option>Loader</option>
    <option>Shopper</option>
</select>
```

I need it to disable this whole select class once I selected an option. Like the user can't select again once he/she selected once. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Simply use onchange property:

```html
<select class="form-control" id="select" onchange="this.disabled=true;">
    <option>Loader</option>
    <option>Shopper</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it on the `onchange` event just like below:

```
 <select class="form-control" id="select">
  <option>Loader</option>
  <option>Shopper</option>
 </select>

 <script>
    $('#select').on('change', function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled')
  });
 <script>
```

this is the same code as @flint but for this to work you have define the `jquery` either from CDN(online url) or you can download the jquery and put it in your page in script tag.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a task for PHP. You'll need to use javascript and jquery would make it even easier.

```
<select class="form-control" id="select">
<option>Loader</option>
<option>Shopper</option>
</select>

<script>
$('#select').on('change', function() {
     $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled')
});
<script>
```

Comment: it's not working.. the select class is not turning off(or disabled) once selected:(((

Comment: @AngelaVillamar have you added `id="select"` as stated in this answer? Because the jQuery snippet is targetting via `id`, it will not work unless the `id` matches

Comment: BTW simply saying its not working isn't helpful, tell us what errors you recieved. since its JavaScript, they'll be visible in browser's Dev Tools console. Press `f12` then locate console.